# Extending type-hinting for PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, type-hinting

Is it possible to extend the type-hinting with another documentor tag in Netbeans?

I'm looking for a way to extend the type-hinting with a `@scope` tag that would allow for includeed files to gain access to an objects scope.

Example:

```
file: template.php
<?php /* @var $this MyObject */
```

This would only allow for type-hinting of public variables and methods. What I'm hoping to do is to extend type-hinting with the `@scope` tag allowing it to gain access to the MyObject scope:

```
file: template.php
<?php /* @scope MyObject */
```

Which would make the file content to act like it would be in the MyObject scope and `$this` would hint private methods.

Now, I have no experience in developing for the Netbeans platform but I have Java experience. If I wanted to accomplish this, where would I start?

Hopefully this is not too weak of a question.

Comment: I am also looking for something almost similar, explained in following [link](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-java-hint.html#creatingthemoduleproject). However I want it for php while the link only explains how to do it for java

Answer (score 2):

In the past (older versions of NetBeans) the type-hinting was showing all the methods from a class (of which object was in use), i.e. all public, protected, private and even static methods. Now, in new releases of NetBeans, this *bug* was fixed and when type-hinting on the object only the accessible methods/properties are type-hinted.

This is simply just because Your template cannot access/call private property/method of a class as well as if You have an object (instance of a class) You shouldn't be able to access/call it's class's static properties/methods.

The same applies if You are willing to type-hint inside of the class - now the type-hinting lists all the public, protected and private methods for `$this->|` (`|` is the cursor) while the static properties and methods are still not listed. On the other side, if You are type-hint on `MyClass::|` now only the static properties/methods are listed and again, when inside the *MyClass* class all the public, protected and public ones are listed while when accessing from outside the private ones are (*very correctly*) missing in the list.

So the functionality You are requesting is wrong and denies the correct principles of encapsulation.

Comment: That may be true for Java or other languages, but PHP allows the scope of a class to be extended to another file. Such behaviour is achieved simply by `include` another file inside a method of a class. In that case the file has access to all methods and properties of enclosing class (even private). The mechanism is very similar to `partial classes` in other languages, except it has no formal syntax in PHP and one has to use type hints. This mechanism is very commonly used by view templates of many PHP frameworks. Whether it is a good practice or not is another matter.

Comment: I'd say its a pretty good practice since you entirely separate markup from code. I.e, I create the view `CreateUserView -> CreateUserView.php` and along with that file I also create the template as `CreateUserView.tpl.php` which my extended View `CreateUserView` automatically loads, and the template is part of the class with the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

I know we're not supposed to suggest any tools, but sometimes I can't resist the feeling that people are trying to solve problems with the wrong one. NetBeans in my opinion is slowly following the steps of Eclipse, which almost entirely abandoned support for PHP over time. There are however other IDE's strictly designed for PHP language, which solve some problems out of the box.

Personally I want a tool that gives me most functionality I need right from the start. I'm not interested in writing plugins, which take my time and may be deprecated over time. So I chose a commercial IDE, which gives me more then I need, and by the way - it perfectly adresses your needs included in the question. If your going to write PHP code then I strongly suggest you consider paying for a proffesional tool.

About the issue itself I'm just going to give an example link to a feature request, which shows how the problem in question was addresed: [Allow protected member access on @var $this (i.e. in views)](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5076). Also there are many more [related features](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1730), that you might find interesting.

So to summarize my opinion is: if your going to tighten the screw then use a screwdriver, not a hammer.