# Which PHP documentation comment for variable type declaration is correct?

Tags: php, documentation

I have searched through different guides & documentations how to declare variable type in documentation correctly but it seems there are several different options.

3 different possibilities are:

```
/** @var integer $sum */
/** @var $sum integer */
/* any of the above but with 1 asterisk */
```

For method parameters and variables in pretty clear how to write as it is written in a lot of different documentations. But what about if we are talking about variables that are not in functions or in View files (MVC design pattern)?

In my workplace we currently use 2 different softwares (**NetBeans** and **PhpStorm**). We noticed that they provide different templates for declaring variable types in documentation.

**In PhpStorm:**

[image]

**In NetBeans:**

[image]

In StackOverflow I have also found 2 different uses ([highly upvoted answer uses NetBeans option with 1 asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798793/3884852) but [in another question it says it's reversed and also uses 2 asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255474/extending-type-hinting-for-php)).

Since we are using Yii2 framework, we also took a look how they write doc comments. They are using [this format](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/views/site/index.php):

```
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
```

---

The last thing I'm interested in (not as important as the question above) is whether I need to declare full path in comments or in usages when declaring object in comments? With full path it would like this:

```
/** @var yii\BaseYii $object */
echo $object::createObject(1);
```

With full path it would look like this:

```
use yii\BaseYii;

/** @var BaseYii $object */
echo $object::createObject(1);
```

We would like to follow PHP standards as accurate as possible.

Any help is appreciated.

---

I'm aware this question might be *too broad* or *unclear what you're asking*, I'll be watching closely too see how it goes.

Comment: the closer standard is psr-5 (not yet accepted), you may take a look: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md

Comment: I have been searching through Google but I wasn't able to found this. Shame on me, actually. I'm also still living in PSR-2 standard. Can you also answer to my last question about when declaring objects? I think it should be added to uses and then in comments use just class name, not full path to it.

Comment: I usually do and see that. ([example](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/Kernel.php#L47))

Comment: Thanks for some information and links. You can write an answer with a few examples how PSR-5 suggests so that other co-workers could find information much easier (if you're ok with that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I commonly see is what [PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) suggest:

```
/** @var int $sum This is a sum. */
$sum = 0;
```

About what if declare the full path or not, those are all valid example:

```
namespace \A\B\C;

use yii\BaseYii;

/** @var BaseYii $yii */
$yii = $factory->getApplication();
```

```
namespace \A\B\C;

/** @var \yii\BaseYii $yii */
$yii = $factory->getApplication();
```

```
namespace \A\B\C;

/** @var \ArrayObject|null $array */
$array = null;
```

```
/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
function now()
{
```

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 */
class Foo
```